# How to Initialize variables in a function to split multipolygons

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial

I am trying to write a function to split multipolygons into single polygons. How do I correctly initialize my variables.

```
create or replace FUNCTION SPLIT_MULTIPOLYGON (
    p_geom IN SDO_GEOMETRY
) 
RETURN SDO_GEOMETRY IS
l_geom SDO_GEOMETRY := p_geom;
v_elements number;

BEGIN

v_elements := sdo_util.GetNumElem(p_geom);
FOR i in 1..v_elements LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'sdo_util.extract(l_geom, i)';
    RETURN l_geom;
END LOOP;

END SPLIT_MULTIPOLYGON;
```

I want every outer ring polygon as a single object. Inner rings don't matter. Later on every polygon should be passed to an existing table.

Comment: Just call `SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT` directly.  E.g., `l_out_geom := sdo_util.extract(l_geom, i);` ... no `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.  But what are you trying to return from your function?  Just the 1st polygon or a set of all the polygons?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak A set of all the polygons...basically a table with one polygon per row.